# Clustering algorithm that penalizes the difference in cluster size

Tags: clustering

Does anyone know a clustering algorithm that penalizes the difference in cluster size (= number of elements)?
If so, is it available in any package (python, R...) ?

For example, the following algorithm is already useful to me. But instead of providing hard min and max sizes, I would like to somehow balance "total point-centroid distance” and “cluster size difference”. E.g it is ok to send a point to a suboptimal cluster that is smaller. I guess there should be some arbitrary parameter/conversion factor to decide. Hope the idea is clear!

k-means-constrained: K-means clustering implementation whereby a minimum and/or maximum size for each cluster can be specified.
https://pypi.org/project/k-means-constrained/

Comment: By "size," do you mean the number of elements or the volumes of the regions around the cluster centers that contain the clusters, or...

Comment: edit: size = number of elements, thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your actual end objective for using such an algorithm?

Comment: Document clustering by field. It is important that the documents somehow belong to the same field, but it is also important to keep the clusters balanced. E.g. think classifying scientific articles: if there are some in "mathematical physics", which would naturally belong to a "math cluster", it is still OK (and preferrable) to throw them into a "physics cluster", if it happens to be much smaller, but not into a "chemistry" cluster.

Comment: K-means is based on euclidean distances of points to cluster centroids. One could modify the distance formula in some weighted and calibrated way incorporating the number of points observed currently in the cluster whose centroid is being considered. If few points, the distance gets reduced; if much points, it gets amplified. I am not sure the algorithm will always converge.